# Can Two AWS api gateway resources point to same lambda authoriser?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Can Two Aws api gateway resources point to same lambda authoriser??

I had the scenario where there are two api gateway resources pointing to same aws lambda authorizer

when i invoke first resource i see the call not going to backend (lambda) and 403 error which is expected because the authz is returning deny(this is expected as one of the validation is failing) but

when i hit the invoke the second resource with same token i see the call going to backend(lambda) which is not expected because even here authoriser should throw  a failure

I am trying to crack this from 2 days and couldn't find a lead

Help is apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

- What is driving the need to share `Lambda Authorizer` with multiple API Gateway resources?
- Did you tie the second API Gateway resource with the `Lambda Authorizer`?

Comment: Yes it is pointing to same authorizer ,